# MySQL Error #1036 - Table 'tablename' is read only - как избавиться?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица весом 3,5 гб (74 млн записей). Я ее скопировал на сервер, путем переноса файлов `tablename.MYD`, `tablename.MYI`, `tablename.frm`. Когда я пытался добавить столбец, возникла ошибка, что таблица мол только для чтения. Как от этого избавиться?

Запрос:

> ALTER TABLE `tablename` ADD `field`
> TINYINT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL

Результат:

```
#1036 - Table 'tablename' is read only
```

- У юзера БД права GRANT.
- При копировании таблицы выставил нужные chmod и chown.

Comment: так никто не переносит таблицы. Поэтому и результаты могут быть непредсказуемыми. обычно таблицу дапмят.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил вопрос, путем создания другой таблицы, и копирования данных из рид-онли в новую, через ПхпМойАдмин. А старую выпилил.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
sudo service mysql restart
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: Вроде бы проблема не в правах на `/var/lib/mysql`.